# Getting location of facebook statuses using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is it possible to get the latitude and longitude for facebook statuses?

I'm using the search API, currently /search?q=foo&type=post, but the JSON I get doesn't have anything about the location. Should I use another API endpoint? Or can it be done with FQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with FQL

```
select latitude, longitude from place where page_id in
        (select place_id from status where uid = me())
```

If you want location of some particular status

```
select latitude, longitude from place where page_id in
        (select place_id from status where status_id = XXXXXXX)
```

If location of status is not set, you'll receive empty result.

Comment: Great! But can I look for any statuses which have a keyword I enter, and then get the location of it. Does facebook allow that? Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, add `and strpos(message, "YORKEYWORD") >=0` to the filter in `select place_id`

Comment: I meant like searching for statuses globally on facebook (to which I have access with my token of course), not just mine, or any other person's?

Comment: I think something like this `... in (select place_id from status where uid in (select your friends, f.e.) and and strpos(message, "YORKEYWORD") >=0)`